# Android SDK API 22 to API 21

Tags: android-developer-api

I loaded Android 5.1.1 (API 22) when I initially downloaded Android Studio I want to go to 5.0.1 (API 21) do I need to uninstall all the API 22 tools and files?

Comment: No, you do not need to uninstall anything

Comment: Use the latest build tools. Independent of compile and target SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they, can exist in parallel. You don't need to uninstall API 22 tools and files.

Comment: Thanks I ended up adding SDK back to 16 and my program finally worked